# Facebook SDK for events

Tags: java, perl, facebook

I want to know if facebook has an sdk that allows adding an event from website to facebook, any examples or suggestions, and we appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a Facebook API called [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). They have Graph also for [Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).

If you want to communicate to Facebook API in java, you can use [restFB](http://restfb.com/).

Comment: and if I want to do it in perl can I? and if there's a working example i will be thankful , thx .

Comment: @shakyeb, you just tagged perl now. I have never used Facebook Graph API in Perl but I'm sure there should be ([Google search](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=Facebook+Graph+API+perl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-ZA:official&client=firefox-a) shows many results).

Comment: @shakyeb, glad to have been of help. Don't forget to accept answers to build your reputation score. :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has Javascript SDK and Graph Api
 [Here](http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/facebook-connect.html) is a Tutorial for it.